How to serve static files on CloudFoundry?
I have a svelte project that basically is a database of links to internal or external files represented visually as a table. Nothing uber-fancy.
So, I've read in other post on StackOverflow that I have to implement a route in order to properly serve static files. I ended up with the following code that perfectly works locally: the execution reaches the code, correctly defines the path of the file and serves the file to browser
the code is put into /src/routes/[...path/+server.js] file:
import path from 'node:path'
import fs from 'node:fs/promises'
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export const GET = async ({ params }) => {

    console.log("i've got the params ", params);

    const workingFolder = import.meta.env.WORKING_DIR;

    console.log("here is my url ", import.meta.url)

    const pathName = `${workingFolder}/static${params.path}`;

    console.log("here is the full path: ", pathName);

    try {
        const file = await fs.readFile(pathName);
        return new Response(file, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': getMimeType(pathName),
            },
        });
    } catch {
        throw error(404, 'File not found.');
    }
}

function getMimeType(filePath) {
    const ext = path.extname(filePath).toLowerCase();
    const mimeTypes = {
        '.html': 'text/html',
        '.css': 'text/css',
        '.js': 'application/javascript',
        '.json': 'application/json',
        '.png': 'image/png',
        '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
        '.gif': 'image/gif',
        '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
        '.txt': 'text/plain',
    };
    return mimeTypes[ext] || 'application/octet-stream';
}

the log output is usually something like it:
i've got the params  { path: '/uploads_folder/cls/20241216-01/9Mb-report.html' }
here is my url  file:///C:/projects/project_name/src/routes/[...path]/+server.js
here is the full path: C:\projects\project_name/static/uploads_folder/cls/20241216-01/9Mb-report.html

Hovewer when I deploy that code to CloudFoundry VM, my code encounters '404 / not found' error and it seems like it never reaches this branch of code, as no log messages available in the logs.
my vite.config.ts is:
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
        include: ['**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    },
    define: {
        'import.meta.env.VERSION': JSON.stringify(version),
        'import.meta.env.WORKING_DIR': JSON.stringify(process.cwd()),
    },
    server: {
        fs: {
            strict: false,
        },
    }
});

My deployment manifest.yml is also nothing fancy:
---
applications:
  - name: mywebsite
    memory: 1G
    instances: 1
    routes:
      - route: mywebsite.mycloudfoundry.com
    stack: cflinuxfs4
    buildpacks:
      - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
    services:
      - serviceOne
      - database
    env:
      PUBLIC_ENVOY_URL: "https://myenvoy.mycloudfoundry.com/"
      BODY_SIZE_LIMIT: 25M

What blocks the route (or alters that) so the code is never reached and how to correct it?


What is the point of this route? SvelteKit already serves all static files in static. 2. Does CloudFoundry have a backend component that could serve dynamic requests? What adapter are you using? The platform is not listed among first-party supported ones.

